# Java Multiple Table Models with CheckBoxes Interfering with each other

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtable, tablemodel

I have a function that creates a generic TabelModel that uses checkbox. However, when I call this method more than once, I find that CheckBoxes from both tables are interfering with each other (click on one table, the other table clicks too).

What could be causing the references to collide with each other?

```
private TableModel<Map<String, Object>> createModel() {
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    TableModel<Map<String, Object>> model = new TableModel<Map<String, Object>>( list,
                                                                                 Arrays.asList( "Name", "Enabled" ),
                                                                                 Arrays.asList( "Enabled" ), null ) {

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt( int row, int column ) {
            final Map<String, Object> object = data.get( row );
            return object.get( columnNames.get( column ) );
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass( int col ) {
            if ( col == 1 ) {
                return Boolean.class;
            }
            return super.getColumnClass( col );
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt( Object aValue, int row, int column ) {
            final Map<String, Object> object = data.get( row );
            object.put( columnNames.get( column ), aValue );
            fireTableCellUpdated( row, column );
        }
    };
    return model;
}
JTable tableA = new JTable ( createModel());
JTable tableB = new JTable ( createModel());
```

Even though tableA and tableB use two different models (or do they?), when I click on a check box in tableA, tableB also reacts to it. Somehow, the checkboxes are becoming entangled. Why does this happen?

Comment: The first thing that I'd do if this were my problem and I were asking here would be to create and post a valid [mcve] with my question, since I'd know that this would be the best and quickest way to get folks to fully understand my problem and then help me.

Comment: What's `data`?  This seems to be a shared resource, so both tables will be using the same `data` source...

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Hmmm.... that's probably the shared resource. Might have to redo the "getValueAt" method

Comment: Or make a copy of `data` and pass it to the create method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field 'data' was being populated with the exact same object, this case a Map. Data is simply an object that holds whatever data this model holds. MadProgrammer is correct that data was being shared, and the solution was make the data loading into the table seperate